# Kerberos Authorization w/ Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, kerberos

I have found many different node.js authentication modules. Ei passport-kerberos. But I am looking to make background https calls to another kerberos authenticated site w/ an authorization token. Does anyone know of any modules for getting an authorization token from credentials in a node app?

Comment: It's not clear from your question, do you simply want to "kinit" using a keytab to access another service or do you want to use proxiable credentials to access the other service with the requestors identity?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wan't to use proxiable credentials from the requester to request to another service.